# Can't see contents of resources folder

Tags: scala, maven, akka

I have a Scala/Akka project which I am building with Maven.

I have a file where I store constants and configuration:

`/src/main/resources/reference.conf`

Now, however, I created a parent Maven module and a child Maven module.

The file has therefore  moved to:

`child-project/src/main/resources/reference.conf`

Now, when I try to use a constant from `reference.conf`, like this:

```
system.settings.config.getConfig("some-constant")
```

I get this error:

```
No configuration setting found for key 'some-constant'.
```

After looking here [No configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011243/no-configuration-setting-found-for-key-akka-version), I used the `maven-shade-plugin`, but with no effect.

In the main `pom.xml` I have this configuration that may be relevant:

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>child-project/src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>child-project/src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>

</build>
```

My `pom.xml` in the parent module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>parent-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.package.name</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Parent project</name>
    <modules>
        <module>child-project</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <scalaVersion>2.11.8</scalaVersion>
        <scalaMajorVersion>2.11</scalaMajorVersion>
        <akkaVersion>2.4.14</akkaVersion>
        <scalaMavenVersion>3.2.1</scalaMavenVersion>
        <akkaHttpVersion>10.0.0</akkaHttpVersion>
        <scalacticVersion>3.0.1</scalacticVersion>
        <scalatestVersion>3.0.1</scalatestVersion>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>child-project/src/main</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>child-project/src/test</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${scalaMavenVersion}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scalaVersion}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.scala</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>child-project/src/main/resources/reference.conf</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-testkit_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-testkit_${scalaMajorVersion}</artifactId>
            <version>${akkaVersion}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalactic</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalactic_${scalaMajorVersion}</artifactId>
            <version>${scalacticVersion}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_${scalaMajorVersion}</artifactId>
            <version>${scalatestVersion}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
                <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

Them `pom.xml` in the child module:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
      <groupId>parent-project</groupId>
      <artifactId>my.package.name</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <artifactId>child-project</artifactId>

  <name>Child Project</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

</project>
```

So how can I see what's declared in `resources.conf`

Comment: Can you provide your parent and child poms.

Comment: I updated my post and included the `pom.xml` files.

Comment: Try enabling debugging for typesafe config to see if the file isn't picked up or if it is something else. https://github.com/typesafehub/config#debugging-your-configuration