# Flink running on remote cluster errors Name or service not known

Tags: cluster-computing, apache-flink

I've test successfully my Flink wordcount app locally, but running on a cluster I faced the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Cannot establish connection to JobManager: hduser@192.168.101.10: Name or service not known
```

My flink cluster created on VirtualBox, including 3 nodes, one Jobmanager and two TaskManager, while JobManager is running on address `192.168.101.10` and port `6123`.

So in java code I use the following command to create `StreamExecutionEnvironment` object

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment("hduser@192.168.101.10", 6123);
```

`hduser` is the user owned JobManager.

I run the jar file in my host OS (that VirtualBox is running on) using command

```
java -cp flink-quickstart-java.jar WordCountStreamingCluster --port 9000
```

**UPDATE**
In case of not using username for cluster address in the following line:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment("192.168.101.10", 6123);
```

I faced the following error:

```
22:04:11,106 INFO  
org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.RemoteStreamEnvironment  - 
Running remotely at 192.168.101.10:6123
22:04:11,422 INFO  
org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient       - 
Starting client actor system.
22:04:11,424 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils            
- Trying to select the network interface and address to use by 
connecting to the leading JobManager.
22:04:11,424 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.util.LeaderRetrievalUtils            
- TaskManager will try to connect for 10000 milliseconds before 
falling back to heuristics
22:04:11,432 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.net.ConnectionUtils                  
- Retrieved new target address /192.168.101.10:6123.
Exception in thread "main" 
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Could not 
start the ActorSystem needed to talk to the JobManager.
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:461)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.StandaloneClusterClient.submitJob(StandaloneClusterClient.java:105)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:442)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:434)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.RemoteStreamEnvironment.executeRemotely(RemoteStreamEnvironment.java:212)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.RemoteStreamEnvironment.execute(RemoteStreamEnvironment.java:176)
at WordCountStreamingCluster.main(WordCountStreamingCluster.java:39)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not start the 
ActorSystem lazily.
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient$LazyActorSystemLoader.get(ClusterClient.java:230)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:459)
... 6 more
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No 
configuration setting found for key 'akka.version'
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:145)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:151)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getString(SimpleConfig.java:206)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:169)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:505)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:119)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.create(ActorSystem.scala:67)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:104)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:92)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.AkkaUtils.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient$LazyActorSystemLoader.get(ClusterClient.java:226)
... 7 more
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you try just `StreamExecutionEnvironment.createRemoteEnvironment("192.168.101.10", 6123);` ? I think it is not necessary to define username for this action.

Comment: @AlexChermenin First I tried without username but I faced error. The error is included in updated post.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011243/no-configuration-setting-found-for-key-akka-version