# reference.conf exception when running flink application

Tags: apache-flink

I have a dropwizard application using Flink to read from Kafka but the application blows up with this exception when I start it:

```
java -jar my-app.jar server my-config.yaml

[2018-01-04T01:04:24,577Z](main)([]) INFO - FlinkMiniCluster - Stopping 
FlinkMiniCluster.
[2018-01-04T01:04:24,591Z](main)([]) WARN - ROOT - unavailable
! com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$UnresolvedSubstitution: 
reference.conf @ jar:file:/my-app.jar!/reference.conf: 804: Could not 
resolve substitution to a value: ${akka.stream.materializer}
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigReference.resolveSubstitutions(ConfigReference.java:108)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.realResolve(ResolveContext.java:179)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.resolve(ResolveContext.java:142)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject$ResolveModifier.modifyChildMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:379)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.modifyMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:312)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.resolveSubstitutions(SimpleConfigObject.java:398)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.realResolve(ResolveContext.java:179)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.resolve(ResolveContext.java:142)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject$ResolveModifier.modifyChildMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:379)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.modifyMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:312)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.resolveSubstitutions(SimpleConfigObject.java:398)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.realResolve(ResolveContext.java:179)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.resolve(ResolveContext.java:142)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject$ResolveModifier.modifyChildMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:379)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.modifyMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:312)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.resolveSubstitutions(SimpleConfigObject.java:398)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.realResolve(ResolveContext.java:179)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.resolve(ResolveContext.java:142)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject$ResolveModifier.modifyChildMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:379)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.modifyMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:312)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.resolveSubstitutions(SimpleConfigObject.java:398)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.realResolve(ResolveContext.java:179)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.resolve(ResolveContext.java:142)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject$ResolveModifier.modifyChildMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:379)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.modifyMayThrow(SimpleConfigObject.java:312)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfigObject.resolveSubstitutions(SimpleConfigObject.java:398)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.realResolve(ResolveContext.java:179)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.resolve(ResolveContext.java:142)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext.resolve(ResolveContext.java:231)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.resolveWith(SimpleConfig.java:74)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.resolve(SimpleConfig.java:64)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.resolve(SimpleConfig.java:59)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.resolve(SimpleConfig.java:37)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl$1.call(ConfigImpl.java:374)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl$1.call(ConfigImpl.java:367)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl$LoaderCache.getOrElseUpdate(ConfigImpl.java:65)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl.computeCachedConfig(ConfigImpl.java:92)
at com.typesafe.config.impl.ConfigImpl.defaultReference(ConfigImpl.java:367)
at com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.defaultReference(ConfigFactory.java:413)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:307)
at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:683)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:245)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:288)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:263)
at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.create(ActorSystem.scala:191)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:106)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.startJobManagerActorSystem(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:300)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.singleActorSystem$lzycompute$1(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:329)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.org$apache$flink$runtime$minicluster$FlinkMiniCluster$$singleActorSystem$1(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:329)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster$$anonfun$1.apply(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:343)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster$$anonfun$1.apply(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:341)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:160)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.start(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:341)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.start(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:323)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:107) ...
```

My Flink stream is pretty basic:

```
environment
        .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>(...)
        .name("source name 1")
        .union(environment.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>(...)
                .name("source name 2"))
        .map(new MyMapFunction())
        .addSink(new PrintSinkFunction<>())
        .name("Sink: Print");
```

Strangely enough, the application runs just fine and successfully creates a FlinkMiniCluster when debugging in IDEA.

I'm using flink 1.4 and did not start a flink job manager when running from IDEA or command line.

Is there a configuration I need to be setting up to run from the command line?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but adding Akka dependencies did not resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - I determined that the akka dependencies from Flink were not being recognized at runtime so I manually added them to my application's pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
   <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>${akka.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
   <artifactId>akka-protobuf_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>${akka.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
   <artifactId>akka-stream_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>${akka.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

As CPS said, the refernce.conf file in shaded JAR has to be a merged file of separated akka modules' reference.conf. To get it, the following shade transformer has to be added to the shade configuration :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            ...
                        </artifactSet>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I experimented a small constraint. I also use the ManifestResourceTransformer to set the mainClass and I had to order the two transformers with ManifestResourceTransformer first and AppendingTransformer in second position (otherwise ManifestResourceTransformer modifies the entry method of the AppendingTransformer).

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by forgetting about using `build-jar` build profile in

```
mvn clean install -Pbuild-jar
```

as documented [in the flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/quickstart/java_api_quickstart.html#build-project)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31011315/1978793) to a similar question solves the issue. This has nothing to do with Flink, but has to do with how akka configuration is handled. From [their documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/configuration.html#When_using_JarJar__OneJar__Assembly_or_any_jar-bundler):

> Akka’s configuration approach relies heavily on the notion of every module/jar having its own reference.conf file, all of these will be discovered by the configuration and loaded. Unfortunately this also means that if you put/merge multiple jars into the same jar, you need to merge all the reference.confs as well. Otherwise all defaults will be lost and Akka will not function.

Using the shade plugin to make the jar solves the problem.